# Is there any way sort Trello cards by custom values?

Tags: trello, sorting, customization, tasks

I sort my bucket list by a `((how much it excites me)*(how much value it will bring me)*(probability of success)/(cost in hours)*(days until [self-imposed] deadline))`.

Is there any way to assign such values to Trello cards and sort by their product?

I've looked at the API, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Trello does not currently have a sort cards function.

You can put those values in the card description.

Manual sort by dragging and dropping cards may be your only option right now.  Easier than changing values for some of those subjective points.